# DKIM Key Implementation

Tags: forms, dkim

I am trying to implement DKIM for my contact forms, and have the required DKIM key from my DirectAdmin control panel. I also assume it is a 1024-bit key since there is an "rsa" reference in the same field.

However, the form also requires a **Selector** and a **Passphrase**, and I have no idea where to obtain these values from.

Here is a screen shot of the form's DKIM panel:

[image: Formloom3 DKIM Panel]